# Finding the correct distribution model

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

The question is as follows:

> Let a be a positive constant and $X$ a random variable, so that:
>
> $P(X>x)=x^{-a}, x\ge1$ and 0 otherwise. Find the correct distribution model [i.e. uniform, Weibull, Normal, etc.] of **ln X**.

My attempt at it:

> for $x\ge1$, $F_X(x)=P(X<x)=1-x^{-a}$, therefore:
>
> $F_Y(y)=P(Y<y)=P(lnX<y)=P(X<e^y )=F_X(e^y)$
>
> $f_y(y)=\frac {d}{dy}F_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_X(e^y)=e^y*(1-e^{y^{-a}})$, for $x \ge 1$ and 0 otherwise.

This looks to me very close to the exponential distribution model, however it is not there yet. It is as if I am missing some trick to get it there, or perhaps my method is wrong. Any hints/guidance will be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Note that it should read $$(1-e^{-ay})$$ and not $$(1-e^{y^{-a}})$$ as you wrote

Comment: Why? If I place $x=e^y$ into $x^{-a}$ wouldn't it be $e^{y^{-a}}$?

Comment: No. Try to replace $a$ with -3 to see why:
$$\left(e^y\right)^3=e^y e^y e^y=e^{3y}$$

Comment: I should really go over my pre-calculus algebra. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to go the other way around.  So

$$\Pr(Y>y) = \Pr(\log X>y) =\Pr(X>e^y) = e^{-ay},$$

so you indeed have an exponential.

Comment: The OP only wanted a hint...

Comment: actually, guidance was ok too ;-)